# Expected unqualified-id before '[' token

Tags: c++, g++

I know this error is generally for syntax errors, but I can't seem to find anything wrong with this code.  Can anyone help me point it out?  Here are the errors I'm getting:

> deli.cc:10:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
>          int [] myCashierNums;
>              ^
>       deli.cc:11:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
>          int [] myOrderNums;
>              ^

Here's the program I compiled using g++ on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class SandwichBoard {
  //private:
    int myMaxOrders;
    int [] myCashierNums;
    int [] myOrderNums;

  //public:
    SandwichBoard (int maxOrders) {
      myMaxOrders = maxOrders;
      myCashierNums = new int [maxOrders];
      myOrderNums = new int [maxOrders];

      // All values initialized to -1
      for (int i = 0; i < maxOrders; i++){
        myCashierNums[i] = -1;
        myOrderNums[i] = -1;
      }
    }

    // For debugging purposes
    void printMyOrders() {
      for (int i = 0; i < maxOrders; i++){
        cout << "Cashier " << myCashierNums[i] << ", ";
        cout << "Order " << myOrderNums[i] << endl;
      }
    }

    int getMaxOrders () { return myMaxOrders; }

};

void cashier(void *in) {

}

void sandwich_maker(void *in) {

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

}
```

Comment: You are confusing C++ syntax with Java.

Comment: Since the size appears to be dynamic, `std::vector<int>` is a better choice.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is *C++*, not *Java*!
Declare arrays like this:

```
int myCashierNums[1000];
int myOrderNums[1000];
```

Please note that the arrays in C++ must have a size at compile time. In the above example, it is 1000.

Comment: Ah, I knew I had been using Java too much lately.  Thanks, I'm going to take T.C.'s advice and use std::vector<int> since the size does have to be dynamic.

Comment: I can't believe I did that... thanks for your answer, I would've been banging my head on my PC for hours. This answer aged very well!

Answer (score 1):

modify:

```
int myMaxOrders;
int* myCashierNums;
int* myOrderNums;
```

add:

```
~SandwichBoard() {
    if (myMaxOrders) {
       delete [] myCashierNums;
       delete [] myOrderNums;
    }
}
```