# expected unqualified-id before '[' token and +

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, arduino-uno, unions

I'm having trouble solving an unknown problem, that I've never experienced on Arduino Nano(ATmega328). I'm building up a drone source code and it has been doing well. But, errors have suddenly appeared in Arduino IDE.
Obviously, I'm a rookie on programming. So help me finding out how to solve this problems.

I got errors like this:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token 

error: 'value' does not name a type

 Quadcopter_Code_Arduino:580: error: expected unqualified-id 
 before '[' token

  struct op[]

           ^

Quadcopter_Code_Arduino:589: error: 'value' does not name a type

   } value;

     ^
```

```cpp
typedef union accel_t_gyro_union
{
  struct
  {
    uint8_t x_accel_h;
    uint8_t x_accel_l;
    uint8_t y_accel_h;
    uint8_t y_accel_l;
    uint8_t z_accel_h;
    uint8_t z_accel_l;
    uint8_t t_h;
    uint8_t t_l;
    uint8_t x_gyro_h;
    uint8_t x_gyro_l;
    uint8_t y_gyro_h;
    uint8_t y_gyro_l;
    uint8_t z_gyro_h;
    uint8_t z_gyro_l;
  } reg;
  struct op[]
  {
    int x_accel;
    int y_accel;
    int z_accel;
    int temperature;
    int x_gyro;
    int y_gyro;
    int z_gyro;
  } value;

};
```

Comment: You might also want to check this question [Expected unqualified-id before '[' token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492647/expected-unqualified-id-before-token)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected unqualified-id before '\[' token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492647/expected-unqualified-id-before-token)

Answer (score 2):

The `struct op[] {` ... `}` looks weird to me. (I even don't know how to read/interprete this.)

Thus, I tested this with gcc on cygwin (in a simplified version):

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.4.0

$ echo 'typedef union u { struct op[] { int i; } value; };
> int main() { return 0; } 
> ' > test-weird-union.c

$ gcc test-weird-union.c   
test-weird-union.c:1:28: error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
 typedef union u { struct op[] { int i; } value; };
                            ^
test-weird-union.c:1:42: error: expected ';' before 'value'
 typedef union u { struct op[] { int i; } value; };
                                          ^
test-weird-union.c:1:42: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
```

(Same output with `gcc -std=c11`.)

The code is probably wrong or at least not standard C.

OK. Thinking additionally about it: How to fix it?

A little bit more background would be nice. Thus, see this as an approach and prove how to apply it:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union accel_t_gyro_union
{
  struct
  {
    uint8_t x_accel_h;
    uint8_t x_accel_l;
    uint8_t y_accel_h;
    uint8_t y_accel_l;
    uint8_t z_accel_h;
    uint8_t z_accel_l;
    uint8_t t_h;
    uint8_t t_l;
    uint8_t x_gyro_h;
    uint8_t x_gyro_l;
    uint8_t y_gyro_h;
    uint8_t y_gyro_l;
    uint8_t z_gyro_h;
    uint8_t z_gyro_l;
  } reg;
  struct op
  {
    int16_t x_accel;
    int16_t y_accel;
    int16_t z_accel;
    int16_t temperature;
    int16_t x_gyro;
    int16_t y_gyro;
    int16_t z_gyro;
  } value;
} accel_t_gyro_union;
```

The following things I have done:

1. Removed the `[]` behind `op` to fix the syntax error.
2. Changed the `int` to `int16_t`. This assures that this code works also on non-16 bit platforms.
3. Added `accel_t_gyro_union` to the end of `typedef`. This might not be necessary but I felt comfortable with this.

Again checked with gcc on cygwin:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 test-weird-union.c
```

At least, no syntax errors. The rest is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

### Definition/Information:

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

> A union is a special class type that can hold only one of its
>   non-static data members at a time.

And

> The union is only as big as necessary to hold its largest data member.
>   The other data members are allocated in the same bytes as part of that
>   largest member.

Also:

Your declaration is incorrect and should be:

```
struct op
{
    int x_accel;
    int y_accel;
    int z_accel;
    int temperature;
    int x_gyro;
    int y_gyro;
    int z_gyro;
} value [SIZE];
```

I advise you to use a specific size for your array, OR a pointer declartion of your struct type to make clear, that you will decide it's heap-size later, but the union on the stack will have a pointer-size for the member...

(Although with empty brackets it still compiles and works in my quick testing... I should read into this behaviour, too. :D)

### Solution:

Use the corrected declaration above.

Advice:
Use a SIZE for the array in the brackets.
If you don't know the size yet, use a pointer for reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The `struct op[] {` ... `}` is nonsense anyway. If you want `struct` type named `op`, it should be outside of union (but it's not really issue, there might be a problem to use it somewhere else):

```
struct A {
    uint8_t  low_byte; // depends on byte order 
    uint8_t high_byte;
};

struct B {
    int          word;
};

union U {
    A  reg;
    B  val;
} variable;
```

But there is no need for the array at all. So the second `struct` should be also anonymous:

```
union accel_t_gyro_union
{
  struct
  {
    uint8_t x_accel_h;
    uint8_t x_accel_l;
    uint8_t y_accel_h;
    uint8_t y_accel_l;
    uint8_t z_accel_h;
    uint8_t z_accel_l;
    uint8_t t_h;
    uint8_t t_l;
    uint8_t x_gyro_h;
    uint8_t x_gyro_l;
    uint8_t y_gyro_h;
    uint8_t y_gyro_l;
    uint8_t z_gyro_h;
    uint8_t z_gyro_l;
  } reg;
  struct
  {
    int x_accel;
    int y_accel;
    int z_accel;
    int temperature;
    int x_gyro;
    int y_gyro;
    int z_gyro;
  } value;
};
```